# Windows explorer group by size custom values

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

Is it possible to change the range of sizes Windows uses for the 'Group by' feature?
Apparently 128MB is Gigantic. Who knew?

```
  Tiny      0 - 10 KB
  Small     10 - 100 KB
  Medium    100 KB - 1 MB
  Large     1 - 6 MB
  Huge      16 - 128 MB
  Gigantic  > 128 MB
```

Comment: Microsoft is still stuck in floppy drive mind sets. Do you know how many floppy drives it would take for a file over 128MB (assuming you split it with WinRAR or something).

Comment: I wonder how old these values are?  I know the property sheets have existed since the days of 98 . . .

Comment: @kobaltz It'd take only one floppy _drive_, but you'd need 89 3.5" 1.44MB HD floppy disks.  Or perhaps 365 5.25" 360KB DD floppy disks. ;)  Reminds me of loading old Sierra games. :)

Comment: @techie lol. true. I remember installing Word/Excel on my Mac with 75MB HDD space. 30 some odd floppy disks later, i was painfully typing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer is *"No, there is no way to change the range of sizes".*

Comment: That is the easy answer :). I was mainly curious if someone has tried to hack it in some way. Probably not, but I will leave this question open for a bit in case someone has.